# "Cannot create a consistent method resolution order" inheriting from another child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am revising OOP in Python and tried inheriting attributes from another child class but I couldn't figure out how or if it is possible. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.pay = pay
  def increase_pay(self, multiplier):
   self.pay = int(self.pay * multiplier)

class Developer(Employee):
  def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
    Employee.__init__(self, first, last, pay)
    self.prog_lang = prog_lang
    self.email = first.lower() + '.' + last.lower() + '@outlook.com'

class BetaTester(Employee, Developer):
  def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang, platform):
    self.platform = platform
```

The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    class BetaTester(Employee, Developer):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Employee, Developer
```

Comment: What specific error did you encounter? Ideally, a good [mcve] should have only the shortest code necessary to demonstrate a specific problem -- if any given line isn't essential to making your point, that line (and anything that depends on it) shouldn't be here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, I'm new here (first post). Let me add the error to the post!

Comment: Thank you -- that's very helpful! (The existing answer guessed right as to what the problem was, but showing it in the question helps others follow, and makes it easier for other people with the same problem search for your question & its answers).

Comment: BTW, insofar as this only happens with Python 3, I added a tag for that version of the language; and since only the class definitions are needed to reproduce the problem, I backed out everything else.

Answer (score 10):

The method resolution order (MRO) is defined by the C3 linearization algorithm, which sounds complicated but it really boils down to this: the class, its parents, *their* parents, etc need to be placed in a list subject to two conditions:

1. Each class appears before its parent(s)
2. If a class inherits from more than one class, its parents appear in the same
   order as they do in `class` statement. That is, given `class A(B, C, D)`, the MRO for `A` will have `B` before `C`, which will be before `D`. (`A`, of course, appears before all 3)

You should be able to see the problem: by this algorithm, the MRO for `BetaTester` has to include `Developer` before `Employer` according to the first rule, but `Employer` has to come before `Developer` according to the second rule. In this case, you can simply swap the two to fix the problem, but there's never any reason to inherit from a class `A` *and* another class the inherits from `A`. Just drop `A` altogether.

```
# Developer is already a descendent of Employee, so BetaTester will be, too
class BetaTester(Developer):
   ...
```

To make sure each class's `__init__` method is called, use `super` to make sure each `__init__` calls the next one in the chain. The most important rule here is to make sure that if a class adds arguments to `__init__`, it has to make sure *not* to pass them on to the next `__init__`. At the same time, it has to accept arbitrary keywords arguments and be *sure* to pass them on. Keyword arguments make it simpler to focus on the arguments you need to deal with, and just pass on the ones you don't.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
    def increase_pay(self, multiplier):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * multiplier)


class Developer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, prog_lang, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang
        self.email = "{}.{}@outlook.com".format(self.first.lower(), self.last.lower())


class BetaTester(Developer):
    def __init__(self, platform, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.platform = platform    


b = BetaTester(first="Bob", last="Jones", pay=90000, prog_lang="Python", platform="Unix")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `super()` in `__init__` method of sub classes
2. Your `BetaTester` is inheriting from `Employee` and `Developer`. Because `Developer` already inherits from `Employee` Python now cannot determine what class to look methods up on first. You don't need to name all base classes of `Developer` here; just inherit from that one class.

here is your fixed code:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.pay = pay


  def increase_pay(self, multiplier):
   self.pay = int(self.pay * multiplier)

emp_1 = Employee('David', 'Jackson', 35000)

print (emp_1.pay)

emp_1.increase_pay(1.2)

print (emp_1.pay)

class Developer(Employee):
  def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
    super().__init__(first, last, pay)
    self.prog_lang = prog_lang
    self.email = first.lower() + '.' + last.lower() + '@outlook.com'



dev_1 = Developer('James', 'McCarthy', 70000, 'C++',)

print(dev_1.first)
print(dev_1.email)


class BetaTester(Developer):
  def __init__(self,first, last, pay, prog_lang, platform):
    self.platform = platform

bt_1 = BetaTester('Jonas', 'Andersen', 45000, 'C#', 'Mobile')

print(bt_1.platform)
```

Comment: If you're going to use `super()` in `Developer`, you should use it in `Employee` as well, even if `Employee` only inherits from `object`. You don't know that some *other* class that inherits from `Employee` or `Developer` might inherit from another class as well, and `Employee` won't necessarily be the last class in the MRO before `object`.

Answer (score 0):

@MehrdadEP has answered very well

I think i should make it easy

suppose there are 2 classes A and B

B inherits from A

Now you are creating a new class C

if you inherit from B you are already inheriting from A. no need to write that in class C(A,B)

observe C(B,A) will not give you error
But C(A,B) will

Another thing is you should use  `Super().__init__()` instead of  `Employee.__init__()`
This may not be handy when doing Hybrid Inheritance due to more than 1 different super classes where you would have to call `classname1.__init__() , classname2.__init__()` and so on

also make sure if you want the attributes defined in SuperClass  then call the `classname.__init__()` so that they are defined in new class's scope otherwise
you will get an *error*

for example

print(b1_1.first) will give an error
to resolve that use `Developer.__init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang)`

and don't forget the self in this `Developer.__init__` calling from subclass `__init__`